# Spring-data-jpa - When does .save() not return the same entity?

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In this code I am saving the main object and a foreign key of that object.
I print out "entity" and "thing" which should be the exact same object. But they aren't. Why?

```
thingList.forEach(entity -> {
            System.out.println(entity);

            // Save if the foreign key exists and isn't already saved in the database
            if(entity.ForeignKey() != null && ForeignKeyRepository.findOne(entity.ForeignKey().getId()) == null)
            {
                ForeignKeyRepository.save(entity.getForeignKey());
            }
            Thing thing = thingRepository.save(entity);
            System.out.println(thing);
        });
```

Comment: Because they aren't the same. If it is a new object your object will be replaced with a hibernate managed entity, which is a proxied instance of your actual entity.

Comment: @M.Deinum actually it is the other way around. If it there is already a managed entity with the same id that one is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the entity is not new and there is already a different instance representing the database row in the session of the `EntityManager` you get that instance, modified to match the one passed as an argument, as the return value.

You can confirm this by inspecting the implementation and the relevant JPA documentation.

The `save` method is implemented in [`SimpleJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java)

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

`em` is the `EntityManager`. From it's `merge` methods documentation:

> Returns: the managed instance that the state was merged to

The [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) section 3.2.7.1 is a little more explicit:

> • If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new managed copy X' of X is created.
>
> • If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity instance X'.
>
> • If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown by the merge operation (or the transaction commit will fail).
>
> • If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation, however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by relationships from X if these relationships have been annotated with the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL annotation.

Comment: I wil accept your answer as it gives good information about what's going on.
But I got something wrong elsewhere and JPA has done everything as you explained it - so it returned the same instance. 
The reason was that I read the output in a wrong way, so I interpreted it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

That is what excepted as they mention in the doc of the save method

> S save(S entity) : Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have **changed the entity instance completely.**